# What arguments for rospy.ServiceProxy?

Tags: rospy, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would want to call a service using python. Currently this command line is working :

```
rosservice call /camera/start_capture
```

but I can't figure out how to do the same thing with python. I already tried this without succes :

```
rospy.ServiceProxy('/camera/start_capture',True)
```

Any idea ?

Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263060/what-arguments-for-rospy.serviceproxy-?/) by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-06-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yzheng0310](https://answers.ros.org/users/30571/yzheng0310/) on 2017-06-02**:
Hi, the second argument in SeriveProxy should be your service class associated with the name '/camera/start_capture'

**Comment by [googooroom](https://answers.ros.org/users/80848/googooroom/) on 2021-08-11**:
from command line, use rosservice info /camera/start_capture to find the service type
from the service type, find out the input/output of this service
when call this using python:
thisService = rospy.ServiceProxy('/camera/start_capture', type)
result = thisService(input)  #input is to trigger the server, result is the output/acknowledgement from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @yzheng0310 said, you must use the class that defines your service.

Let's suppose that the service used by `/camera/start_capture` is a `StartCatpure` that is defined in your package, and let's suppose that your package is named `my_package`.

In this case you would do the following:

```
import rospy 
from my_package.srv import StartCatpure
start_capture = rospy.ServiceProxy('start_capture_node', StartCapture)
```

Now, let's call the service. In this case, supposing that the service doesn't accept parameters:

`start_capture()`

You can check the ROS Tutorial [Writing a SImple Publisher and Subscriber in Python](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) that explains step by step.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-08-04**:
(Small hint: use the 101010-Button to format code)